# Monk Proficiency with Spears/Javelins

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, monk, attack, two-weapon-fighting

I have some questions about monks in DnD 5e. I want to make a monk that uses dual spears/javelins, one in each hand so he can have the option to throw them when necessary.

Because Spears/Javelins are monk weapons do they get the modifier bonus for being monk weapons? Or do I need a Fighter's two weapon fighting syle to even gain the bonus? That's all thanks!

Comment: But it says in the rulebook that Javelins are a melee weapon so I thought the Thrown property was just an option. But if that's the case, I am just talking about Spears in then.

Comment: @nitsua60 Both spears and javelins are simple melee weapons with the thrown property.

Answer (score 3):

First....I just have to say this is a brilliant idea and I have no idea why I have not seen this attempted anywhere before now.  With that being said, on to the answer:

First, to end any speculation about throwing weapons:

**Thrown**

> "...If a weapon has the 'thrown' property, you **can** throw the weapon to make a ranged attack.   If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier ... that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon..."

So yes, Thrown weapons are melee weapons first and foremost that CAN (or can not) be used to also make ranged weapon attacks.  They are not ONLY ranged weapons, like the bow and crossbow; found in their own Ranged Weapon table.

Lastly, yes, because monks are proficient in Spears and Javelins, and a 'Monk Weapon' is any weapon the Monk is proficient in as well as Unarmed Strikes; Spears and Javelins DO benefit from the *'Martial Arts'* bonus and everything included under the *'Martial Arts'* class ability.  Including being able to make an unarmed strike as a bonus action when you use the Attack Action to either throw a Spear or Javelin or attack with either in melee combat.

On the note of Dual Wielding; be mindful that you can hold a Spear or Javelin in both hands if you really wanted to; but the rules on Two Weapon Fighting (Dual Wielding) require both weapons to have the 'Light' property before you are able to swing with BOTH in the same turn; unless you have the particular feat that says otherwise.

Comment: In rules terms, even when you throw a weapon with the thrown property (with the exception of darts), you are still making a melee weapon attack.  It is not a ranged attack (which are only made with weapons in the ranged category, bow, crossbow, etc), it is an attack at range.

Comment: @LegendaryDude in rules terms, note PHB page 195  "...When you make a ranged attack, you fire a bow or a crossbow, hurl a handaxe, or otherwise send projectiles to strike a foe at a distance..."  Add the part about thrown: "You can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack" ... and yes, a thrown weapon becomes a **ranged attack** with a melee weapon.

Comment: Yes, but does it not also count as a melee weapon attack?  It is an attack being made with a melee weapon.

Comment: @LegendaryDude it's a melee weapon attack and a ranged attack but not a ranged weapon attack.

Comment: @DaleM That's what I was trying to get at.  It's an important distinction because it allows you to benefit from features that apply to melee weapon attacks while attacking from range.

Comment: @LegendaryDude indeed

Comment: @ .... well I'm not sure.  Now I'm confused.  It is distinctly a Ranged Attack , made with a Melee Weapon.  It is not (if thrown) A melee weapon attack with a melee weapon, or that would be in melee.... wouldn't it?  PHB page 195 gives a thrown example in 'Handaxe' .  It becomes a Ranged Attack with a melee weapon for that duration.  Still a Melee *weapon* not a ranged weapon, but not currently a melee weapon attack in that instance.

Comment: This may help, from the Sage Advice Answer Compendium:  "...What does “melee weapon attack” mean: a melee attack with a weapon or an attack with a melee weapon? *It means a melee attack with a weapon. Similarly, “ranged weapon attack” means a ranged attack with a weapon.* ..."

Comment: You don't need a free hand to make unarmed strikes.

Comment: I agree with @Derek. Monk unarmed strikes can be kicks, headbutts, elbows, knees...

Comment: @DerekStucki hmm.... you DO have a point there.  Since Unarmed Strikes no longer appear on the weapon table.... and don't count as weapon attacks, and can be anything from a headbutt or kick to any forceful blow; I guess that means you DON'T need any of your hands free.  Well that changes quite a bit..... I've edited that part out.