# How do I optimize dual throwing weapons for damage and mobility?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, feats, optimization, two-weapon-fighting

Starting my first D&D 5e game soon. I'm planning on making a dual-wielding Javelin/Spear character who darts around throwing his weapons kinda like Kalista from League of Legends. What Feats or class do I need to make such a character to be effective in combat? To be more specific, I want him to be dealing alot of damage while staying out of melee range.

Comment: related: [Can You Two-Weapon Fight With a Dart?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77323/23970)

Comment: Effective in combat. Attacking and doing damage while at the same time trying to stay out of melee.

Comment: also topically related: [Does Dual Wielder let an Eldritch Knight summon two bonded weapons](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77311/23970) and [Are you still two-weapon fighting if you throw...](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77364/23970)

Answer (score 2):

I expect you certainly can, and I have seen people do it in the past. Here is a list of things you should be aware of.

1. Your weapon is effectively a melee weapon, but since spears/javelins have the thrown weapon property, they can also be thrown. There is no issue throwing your spears as a regular character.
2. **Required feature: Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style.** Gives you some nice damage bonuses. This limits you to a class with this feature (e.g. [Fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#FightingStyle)/[Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#FightingStyle)).
3. **Required feat: [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/dual-wielder)** (PHB, p. 165). This feat allows you to actually use your spears/javelin for two-weapon fighting. It also gives you an AC bonus, and the ability to draw/stow two weapons at once instead of one (useful I imagine when you are throwing your weapon and need to draw another).
4. **Suggested feat: [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/mobile)** (PHB, p. 168). You are going to spend a lot of time moving out of people's range and giving them attacks of opportunity against you. I recommend this because all you have to do is make a melee attack and then retreat. It has some other nice bonuses as well.
5. **Suggested Race: [Variant Human](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/human#VariantHuman)** (if you're allowed to use it), since it gives you a feat. Recommend getting Dual Wielder or Mobile.

I'll update as more ideas surface for this character. I expect there may also be some discussion as to my choices.

Also, you should take a moment to take a look at this for more ideas: [Monk Proficiency with Spears/Javelins](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77329/monk-proficiency-with-spears-javelins)

Comment: I believe rangers do have access to the Two weapon Fighting style as well. Though with 2 feats you are probably indeed better off taking a fighter.

Comment: Ranger would probably work as well I expect, I don't see any major benefit from the fighter to the ranger. Depending on campaign settings though the ranger might be better.

Comment: Fighter gets more attacks, more feats, better armor, and more useful class features. Unless you specifically need a survivalist or the ability to cast ranger spells, ranger is almost always a bad choice. In fact you can make a better ranger with just the fighter class.

Comment: @Lokiare it sounds more like you can make an inferior fighter with just the ranger class. The fighter is only a "better ranger" if you ignore most of the ranger class abilities.

Comment: You can also get the best ranger spells faster from a Bard who can do the rangers skills better due to expertise. With the added feats you can pretty much pick up anything the ranger can do.

Comment: Most of the ranger abilities are very limited in use. The only time a ranger would use these abilities constantly would be a long trek in the wilderness tracking a specific enemy.

Comment: You may want to modify this answer to take into account the "Thrown Weapon Fighting" fighting style from _Tasha's Cauldron of Everything_.