# Are you still two-weapon fighting if you've thrown one of your two weapons and are no longer holding it?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, two-weapon-fighting, throwing-things

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77323/can-you-two-weapon-fight-with-a-dart) we see that two-weapon fighting with darts is not possible because they are not melee weapons.  Let's replace the darts in that scenario with daggers, which are valid *light* melee weapons for two-weapon fighting, and also have the *thrown* property.

Two-weapon fighting says:

> **Two-Weapon Fighting**.
>
> When   you take    the Attack  action  and attack  with    a   light   melee   weapon  that    you’re  holding in  one hand,   you can use a   bonus   action  to  attack  with    a   different   light   melee   weapon  that    you’re  holding in  the other   hand.   You don’t   add your    ability modifier    to  the damage  of  the bonus   attack, unless  that    modifier    is  negative.
>
> If either  weapon  has the thrown  property,   you can  throw  the weapon, instead of  making  a   melee   attack  with    it.

Consider this scenario:

Bob the rogue has two daggers drawn and ready to go.  He throws his first dagger as his attack action, satisfying the condition of "when    you take    the Attack  action  and attack  with    a   light   melee   weapon  that    you’re  holding in  one hand."

At this point, he is no longer holding this weapon in hand because he has thrown it.  He is now holding only one dagger, in his other hand.  In this case, the condition above has been met, but does he get to use the bonus action to attack with a "different light melee weapon [held in his] other hand" *even though he is now wielding only a single weapon?*

In other words, is the bonus attack granted at the moment the first attack made, as long as you meet that first condition of "attack[ing] with  a   light   melee   weapon  that    you’re  holding in  one hand," regardless of how many weapons you end up holding after the first attack?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Yup, this works.

He takes the Attack action, and meets all of the prerequisites of TWF. Check.

He throws a dagger, as TWF allows. Check.

Now, as you describe, he's holding a light, one-handed, melee weapon and can attack with it. He can either make a melee attack or throw it, per the last line of TWF.

If he could not attack because he's only holding one weapon, the last line of TWF would be nonsense. The conditions were met *when he chose the Attack action*, so he can carry out all of its steps.

Comment: Also, by reading of the rules text, it doesn't anywhere say that you need to be wielding two weapons at once - just that you need to first attack with one weapon, wielded in one hand, end then attack with a different weapon, wielded in the other hand.  You could throw, draw, then throw, and still use two weapon fighting in spite of never having had more than one weapon in hand at a time.

Comment: @BenBarden: The interpretation in your comment is contradicted by the official ruling in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=13) (updated in October 2020): "**Can I make an attack with one weapon, then draw a second weapon with my other hand and qualify to use two-weapon fighting?** To use the two-weapon fighting bonus action (PH, 195), you must have both weapons in hand when you make the first attack. [...]"

Comment: Corresponding Q&A: [Does Two-Weapon fighting work if you aren't holding both weapons when you take the Attack action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120599/33569)